# How does GADTs affect type inference in this case?

Tags: haskell, gadt

Say I have a monad that emits soft failure through Writer. A simplified version goes like this (for the record, I'm using GHC 9.0.2):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BlockArguments #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
-- {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Lib where

import Control.Monad.Writer.CPS
import Data.Maybe

verify :: MonadWriter [String] m => some -> args -> m ()
verify _ _ = fix \(_ :: m ()) ->
  do
    let warn = tell . (: [])
        a = Just 1 :: Maybe Int
        b = Just [1, 23] :: Maybe [Int]
        c = Just (id :: forall a. a -> a)
        -- isJust' :: String -> Maybe a -> m ()
        isJust' tag v = unless (isJust v) do
          warn $ tag <> " is Nothing"
    isJust' "a" a
    isJust' "b" b
    isJust' "c" c
```

All goes fine until I add `GADTs` extension, then GHC fails to find the most general type for `isJust'`:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Maybe Int
        Actual: Maybe [Int]
    • In the second argument of ‘isJust'’, namely ‘b’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: isJust' "b" b
      In the expression:
        do let warn = tell . (: [])
               a = ...
               ....
           isJust' "a" a
           isJust' "b" b
           isJust' "c" c
   |
22 |     isJust' "b" b
   |                 ^

/var/tmp/demo/src/Lib.hs:23:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a0 -> a0’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Maybe Int
        Actual: Maybe (a0 -> a0)
    • In the second argument of ‘isJust'’, namely ‘c’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: isJust' "c" c
      In the expression:
        do let warn = tell . (: [])
               a = ...
               ....
           isJust' "a" a
           isJust' "b" b
           isJust' "c" c
   |
23 |     isJust' "c" c
   |                 ^
```

At which point I have to uncomment type annotation for `isJust'` to get this to type check - I'm wondering what is at play here, I don't think I'm using any GADTs features?

Side note 1: I usually just slam a `NoMonomorphismRestriction` to see if it helps, it didn't.

Side note 2: That use of `fix` is just for getting a hold on that `m` in the presence of `ScopedTypeVariables` - a side question is whether there are better ways to do this without relying on `verify` having an explicit type signature (say this function is defined inside an instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not `GADTs` but `MonoLocalBinds`, which is automatically enabled by `GADTs`. The issue is that `isJust' :: String -> Maybe a -> m ()` has a polymorphic type signature, meaning you get to choose what `a` is every time you call it. At least, it would be polymorphic *if* `MonoLocalBinds` wasn't enabled. Per [the documentation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/let_generalisation.html#extension-MonoLocalBinds):

> With MonoLocalBinds, a binding group will be generalised if and only if
>
> - It is a top-level binding group, or
> - Each of its free variables (excluding the variables bound by the group itself) is closed (see next bullet), or
> - Any of its binders has a partial type signature (see Partial Type Signatures).

If a variable does not satisfy one of the three bullets, its type is not generalized, i.e. it does not get to be polymorphic.

There is a rigorous definition of what a "closed variable" is, but the important part is:

> *if a variable is closed, then its type definitely has no free type variables.*

The second argument of `isJust'` has type `Maybe a` for some unknown `a`, meaning it is *not* closed *(edit: see Li-yao Xia's correction in the comments)*. So, bullet 1 is not satisfied because `isJust'` is defined within `verify`, bullet 2 is not satisfied because the second argument of `isJust'` is not closed, and bullet 3 is not satisfied because there are no holes in the type of `isJust'`. Thus, `isJust'` is *not* polymorphic after all.

All this means is that the `a` in `String -> Maybe a -> m ()` is actually a fixed type that GHC has to infer. It sees you call `isJust' "a" (a::Maybe Int)` and assumes `a ~ Int`, but then it sees `isJust' "b" (b::Maybe [Int])` and assumes `a ~ [Int]` as well. Obviously this is a problem, so GHC complains. The only thing adding the type signature does is tell GHC to make `isJust'` polymorphic.

Note that you *can* have `GADTs` and `NoMonoLocalBinds` at the same time, but because type inference with GADTs is tricky this will probably just cause more problems when you actually use GADTs.

Comment: The characterization of "closed" is incorrect. It is not about the arguments of the function ("the second argument of `isJust'`...is not closed"), but about the identifiers used in its body.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Thank you for clarifying -- I am not incredibly familiar with MonoLocalBinds. Since the argument is used in the body (along with other polymorphic functions), this should still apply though, right?

Comment: `v` is a bound variable so the clause "each of its [`isJust'`'s] free variables is closed" does not apply to it. The free variables of `isJust'` are `unless`, `isJust`, `warn`, `$` and `<>`. It's `warn` that is not closed.

Comment: The rest of the answer is great!